# Python Automation from a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, automation

i have searched and searched i am new to python i am trying to automate a process where as i have a csv file with thousands of rows of data and what i need to do is click at certain points on my screen and then enter the data that is in the first row and then repeat to the next row.

so click here and enter whats in cell A2 then click here and enter cell A3 then click here and enter cell A4 once them are completed loop and do the same process but on Row B

Sorry for my description but i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

i had done some more searching and trial and error and managed to solve it myself thought i would post incase it could help someon else.

```
import openpyxl
import pyautogui
import time
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(R'C:\Users\scott\Desktop\PYTHON NEW\book1.xlsx')
type (wb)
wb.get_sheet_names()
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
lastRow = Sheet.max_row
for i in range(2,lastRow + 1):
    #print(Sheet.cell(row=i,column=7).value)
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 2
    pyautogui.click(183,57)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    c=Sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(c))
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #pyautogui.click(200,200)
```